# Android OnClickListener to update text within same ListView row

Tags: java, android, listview, onclicklistener

I am making a list view that contains (amongst a few other things) 2 ImageViews and a TextView.  The two ImageViews are plus and minus icons, when they are pressed, they need to update the number inside the TextView.  They also need to trigger code that will update the sum of the TextViews, below the ListView.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

      holder = new ViewHolder();
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.basket_item, null);
      holder.plus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count_add);
      holder.minus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count_minus);
      holder.counter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_counter);
      convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.id = position;

    holder.counter.setId(position);
    holder.counter.setText(count[position]);


    holder.plus.setId(position);
    holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        if (count[id] < 999) {
          count[id]++;
          totalcount++;
        }
      }
    });

    holder.minus.setId(position);
    holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        if (count[id] > 1) {
          count[id]--;
          totalCount--;
        }
      }
    });

    return convertView;

  }
}

class ViewHolder {
  ImageView plus;
  ImageView minus;
  TextView counter;
  int id;
}
```

I believe, to update the counter in the TextView, I need to somehow get my 'holder' inside the OnClickListner, however, as it is not declared as final, I can't.

Is there an easier way to do this, or am I missing a trick here?

Comment: you don't change the text in the textview directly, because of the view recycling thing. what you do is that you change the underlying data, and ask for a refresh of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implement the notifyDataSetChanged() that calls the getView once again. And after that invalidate the textView. But I am not fully sure about the need to call invalidate() here.

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
     int id = v.getId();

     if (count[id] > 1) {
       count[id]--;
       totalCount--;
       notifyDataSetChanged(); 
       holder.counter.invalidate();
     }
   }
 });
```

Comment: I have not yet tried with just adding notifyDataSetChanged(); (need to finish another part to populate the list first).  However the line holder.counter.invalidate(); errors saying "Variable 'holder' is accessed from within inner class. Needs to be declared final."

Comment: Yes, when you declare the object holder it should be declared as final - that is:  final ViewHolder holder; When you call notifyDataSetChanged and made the holder final it should work!

Comment: It does.  I could have sworn when I tried to make it final earlier, it threw an error... Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about it.I hope it do. Try to paste this line under the Onclick method itself.

"holder.counter.setText('YOUR TEXT totalcount');"

Comment: This is what I initially attempted to do, however I get the error:    "Variable 'holder' is accessed from within inner class. Needs to be declared final."

Comment: try to do like this "again get the view with in Onclick method then set the text to that". TextView counter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_counter); counter.setText(totalcount);